# What is the meaning of 4th `%` in `libraryDependencies`in sbt

Tags: sbt

In the following setting, I suppose the format is `"groupId" % "artifactId" % "version"`

```
libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" % "specs2_2.10" % "1.14" % "test"
```

What does `test` mean?

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Dependencies.html)

> Declaring a dependency looks like this, where groupId, artifactId, and revision are strings:
>
> ```
> libraryDependencies += groupID % artifactID % revision
> ```
>
> or like this, where configuration can be a string or Configuration val:
>
> ```
> libraryDependencies += groupID % artifactID % revision % configuration
> ```

So the 4th `%` meaning is to add a dependency only to a certain configuration. In your example it is `"test"`, which could also be written as `Test`.

The meaning is that you don't usually need to keep in your runtime classpath classes for test framework which you only use in staging environment and never use in production.

To learn more about configurations you can read [this](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Scopes.html).